# Does clone() generate another reference for the event handlers?

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.classSelect').change(function() {
            // somethings
        });
    });
</script>
```

And is applied to all `.classSelect`. Than, if I clone some of these div and I insert in the page, I see that this handler works automatically also for these cloned elements.

So every time I clone an element I create a new handler-reference for that element? Or I'm wrong somethings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method takes an additional boolean parameter allowing you to control this behavior (whether the events and data should be cloned):

> withDataAndEvents: A Boolean indicating whether event
>   handlers should be copied along with
>   the elements. As of jQuery 1.4,
>   element data will be copied as well.

And in version 1.5 there is a second argument `deepWithDataAndEvents`:

> deepWithDataAndEvents: A Boolean
>   indicating whether event handlers and
>   data for all children of the cloned
>   element should be copied. By default
>   its value matches the first argument's
>   value (which defaults to false).

So when you clone an element event handlers attached to the source element will be executed as well by the cloned elements.

Comment: Uhm! But that works also if I don't put any additional parameter when I clone the element :O

Comment: @markzzz, there is the following quote in the documentation: `For 1.5.0 the default value is incorrectly true. This will be changed back to false in 1.5.1 and up.`. Could this explain the behavior you are observing?

Comment: Quite sure I have the latest version of jQuery... so the default value should be false, and that's so strange. But it works ?!?!